# Mongoose: update only element in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a database structure of this type for managing product-related attributes:

```
const AttributeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    store_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Store',
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    values: [{
        "name": String,
        "price": Number,
        "created_at": {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        "updated_at": {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
    }],
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

As values I have the following:

```
{
"attribute": {
        "name": "Size",
        "store_id": "62ba2a8eee4b1cb418546cf2",
        "values": [
            {
                "name": "42",
                "price": 0,
                "_id": "62c36671019adad103c29e4f",
                "created_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.205Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.205Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "44",
                "price": 0,
                "_id": "62c36671019adad103c29e50",
                "created_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "46",
                "price": 2,
                "_id": "62c36671019adad103c29e51",
                "created_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "48",
                "price": 5,
                "_id": "62c36671019adad103c29e52",
                "created_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "62c36671019adad103c29e4e",
        "created_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-04T22:15:13.206Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Now I would like to update only one key contained in the values node

Request with params "62c36671019adad103c29e4f" for size "42":

```
{
    "name":"Size",
    "size_id": "62c36671019adad103c29e4f",
    "store_id":"62ba2a8eee4b1cb418546cf2",
    "values": [
        {"name": "420", "price": 0.00}
    ]
}
```

Execution required

```
const update = {
        name: req.body.name,
        store_id: req.body.store_id,
        values: req.body.values,
        updated_at: Date.now(),
    }

let doc = await Attribute.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
                returnOriginal: false
            });
```

but rightly it updates all the values node for me then replaces everything with the value of the last request.
How do I update only the value I want?
In this case size 42?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solution given below?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an elemMatch operator to search into the fields within an array of objects. See [Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
db.myCollection.find({
   _id: ObjectId("62ba2a8eee4b1cb418546cf2"),
   values: {
      $elemMatch: {_id: '62c36671019adad103c29e4f'}
   }
}, {
   $set:{
      'values.$.name': '420'
   }
});
```